# Redgate SQL Connect and static Data

Tags: c#, sql-server, redgate

I use `Redgate SQL Connect` in C# and want to active Data folder of my SQL Connect project to Define static table. How can I do?

EDIT :
 Static Table are tables that have Static Data

Comment: What do you mean by "want to activeData folder", and what's a "static table" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Connect doesn't currently support source controlling static data. There is already an awareness that it needs to be implemented and you can add your voice to the list here: http://redgate.uservoice.com/forums/140800/suggestions/2450911

SQL Source Control, a plugin for SSMS, does support static data.

Answer (score 0):

Brian is right. This isn't supported yet, although it will be in due course. You can use SQL Source Control to add the static data. To deploy the static data changes, you can use SQL Data Compare separately from SQL Source Control and SQL Connect.